# Локальная переменная уничтожается при выходе из функции, а что происходит с динамически выделенной памятью?

Tags: c++, c

```
#pragma once
template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
    List();
    ~List();
    void push_back(T data);
    int GetSize() { return Size; }
    T& operator[](const int index);

private:
    template<typename T>
    class Node 
    {
    public:
        Node* pNext;
        T data;
        Node(T data = T(), Node *pNext = nullptr)
        {
            this->data = data;
            this->pNext = pNext;
        }
    };
    int Size;
    Node<T> *head; 
};

template<typename T>
List<T>::List()
{
    Size = 0;
    head = nullptr;
}


template<typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{

}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::push_back(T data)
{
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new Node<T>(data);
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T>* _current = this->head;
        while (_current->pNext != nullptr)
        {
            _current = current->pNext;
        }
        _current->pNext = new Node<T>(data);
    }
    ++Size;
}

template<typename T>
inline T& List<T>::operator[](const int index)
{
    int counter = 0;
    Node<T>* current = this->head;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (counter == index)
        {
            return current->data;
        }
        current = current->pNext;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Я пытаюсь по туториалу реализовать подобие контейнера `list` из STL. Но никак не могу понять, как работает `push_back` в этом коде. `_current` — это же локальная переменная и должна уничтожаться при выходе из функции. Получается, что если я выделяю память и присваиваю ее пусть даже локальной переменной, то она будет оставаться в памяти?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, переменная `_current` — это локальная переменная и она действительно уничтожится при выходе из функции. Но обратите внимание, что `_current` — это *указатель* на поле `head`. Получается, что указатель на новый объект, который создается в методе `push_back`:

```
_current->pNext = new Node<T>(data);
```

не теряется — он будет сохранен в объекте списка.

Однако выделенная память в данном случае не будет освобождаться автоматически, как вы правильно заметили:

> Получается, что если я выделяю память и присваиваю ее пусть даже
>   локальной переменной, то она будет оставаться в памяти?